# placing www infront of my domain displays directory view

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I'm sorry if this is elsewhere on SO, but I can't find anything that can help me with my issue.

A while back, I updated my server, which wrecked the LAMP stack. So I installed it all again, but I must have done something wrong.
When I try to enter my domain, with www infront, it displays the directory view.
It's like it totally disregards my .htaccess file.

I have the following file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
{comments}

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com domain.com   
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

{comments}

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

{comments}
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Besides that, I have the following line in the top (amongst some redirects) of my .htaccess file

```
Options -Indexes
```

I have no idea, how to fix this.
I don't want people in the directory view. And unfortunately some browsers automatically place www infront, plus a lot of people write www in front of urls.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself.
I found out that I had a default.conf, that the www trigered.
So changing this to direct to my folder for the domain, worked.
Thanks to @Alexandre Fenyo for the help

Answer (score 1):

1- Replace `ServerAlias domain.com domain.com` by `ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com`.

2- Replace `AllowOverride None` by `AllowOverride All` in your Apache configuration file.

This way, your `.htaccess` will be able to override some general configuration primitives, like displaying indexes.

Once it works, modify `AllowOverride All` to put only what is really needed, for security reasons.

Comment: Just tried it. Restarted apache, but it didn't work. Still seeing the directory view.

Comment: Does your .htaccess is readable by the user that runs apache processes?

Comment: Is this during an http or an https connection?

Comment: Do you have `/var/www/html` in another configuration file?

Comment: It should be readable, since the rewrite module works if I'm not having www in front of the domain. It's a http connection, I don't have https configured. Not to that specific folder, only subfolders.

Comment: Try to replace `ServerAlias domain.com domain.com` by `ServerAlias www.domain.com domain.com`

Comment: That didn't do the trick either. Maybe it's just me, but should `service apache2 restart` make sure that new conf would be loaded?

Comment: Yes, `service apache2 restart` does the job.

Comment: do you have a httpd.conf file in /etc/apache2?

Comment: Then that didn't work either. I have no idea what's wrong. I have other domains, and there's no problem with them.

Comment: No, I have the following files: apache2.conf, ports.conf, envvars, magic

Comment: OK, can you do `grep var/www/html /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`?

Comment: Yes. Just did that..Didn't do anything

Comment: weird behaviour. No more idea :-(

Comment: Okay, Thanks for trying though